# Android Java Compress Video size before upload

Tags: java, android, video-compression

I am developing an app which has similar features to instagram for learning purposes.
I want to upload a video from gallery to my cloud.
In iOS, Swift already offers an in-built function which fixes the quality to my needs (.low, .medium, .high).
Is there any way to achieve a similar behavior in android?

I have tried multiple things like Silicompressor and lightCompressor but they did not work.

The workflow is:

```
-> select video from storage
-> resize video size in background without saving it as a new one in the storage
-> uploading the selected and compressed video
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In android there's no built-in method for that.
You can create your own transcoder using `MedixMuxer`, `MediaCodec` or FFMPEG or you can add existing libraries like: https://github.com/natario1/Transcoder, https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder, https://github.com/linkedin/LiTr

Also resizing video without saving it as a new one is not a good idea. I mean a user probably wouldn't like that his video is changed. You can save it to cache folder in android - `Context.getCacheDir()`